# Run script once unattended once when system has booted

Tags: filesystem

I am currently creating a very minimal image for the Raspberry Pi 4. And I need the image itself to be as small as possible in order to reduce the time to flash the SD-card.

I do however, want to expand the file-system automatically when the Raspberry Pi 4 first boot.

I just threw this into a bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x -e
raspi-config nonint do_expand_rootfs
rm -- "$0"
reboot
```

Running this works, but how to I run this just once when the Pi boots?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a quite simple way to do this!

First, place your expand-script in a good folder, like `/usr/local/bin/expand.sh`, and make it executable with `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/expand.sh`

Then, edit `/boot/config.txt` and add the following furthest down:

```
[expansion]
init=/usr/local/bin/expand.sh
```

Reboot, and then observe the expanded filesystem with `df -h`

Comment: Very interesting. Where do you get this information? I cannot find it at [Conditional filters in config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/conditional.md).